# How to update a table based on a raw dataset?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table like this:

```
// users
+---------+------------+
| user_id | reputation |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | null       |
| 2       | null       |
+---------+------------+
```

Also I have an array like this: `[1 => 15, 2 => 83]`.
I can parse that array and restruct it to any case needed. I want to know how can I update that value to that table like this:

```
// users - expected result
+---------+------------+
| user_id | reputation |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 15         |
| 2       | 83         |
+---------+------------+
```

An idea how can I do that?

---

I want a query similar to this:

```
update users u
join ( ... ) as temp
on u.user_id = temp.user_id
set u.reputation = temp.rep
```

Comment: What's the question you have stated that you can parse that array and restruct it and presumably you can push it into a temp table on row per array element and the update statement looks ok(ish)

Comment: `.. join ( ... ) as temp ..` should be `.. join ( SELECT 1, 15 UNION SELECT 2, 83 ) as temp (user_id, rep) ..`.